# What is the verb="*"?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

Can any one tell me , when we register the custom HTTPHander in web.config like below

```
 <add verb="*" path="SampleHandler.new" 
    type="SampleHandler, SampleHandlerAssembly" />
```

in this What is the meaning of the **verb="*"** and what is the it's use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means all HTTP verbs: GET, POST, HEAD, PUT and DELETE

The verb list can be either a comma-separated list of HTTP verbs (for example, "GET, PUT, POST") or a start-script mapping (for example, the wildcard character * [an asterisk]).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d6sws33%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

It means that the handler will execute for all verbs - ie. GET, PUT, etc.

HTTP Verbs:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Default configuration:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bya7fh0a.aspx

It can be used to specify that, for example, a certain handler should only process POSTs not GETs.